Append function calls to asyncio.gather until condition is fullfilled?
I am downloading folders with aiohttp. However i want to stop downloading when the hdd has only 200gb of free space: Right now I am doing it like this:
async def main():
    split_list = numpy.array_split(folders_to_download, int(len(folders_to_download)/100 + 1))
    for numpy_list in split_list:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            total, used, free = await aioshutil.disk_usage("/media/hdd")
            if free * 10 ** (-9) >= 200:
                list_to_pass = numpy_list.tolist()
                tasks = [download_folder(folder, session) for folder in list_to_pass]
                await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

I am splitting the list of folders which I have into into chunks of lists with approx. 100 entries and then I download them in parallell using asyncio.gather. But it is not very efficient because asyncio waits for the whole 100 folders to be downloaded before the next 100 folders are downloaded.
What I would like to achieve: As soon as one folder has finished downloading I would like to start downloading the next folder until there is 200gb of free space left on the hdd. Then I would like to stop appending folders to the queue and just finish downloading the folders which are in the queue.

I think your best option is probably to just spin up 100 worker tasks and check the space on each iteration. Roughly like:
LIMIT = 200 * 10 ** 9

async def worker(queue, session):
    _, _, free = await aioshutil.disk_usage("/media/hdd")
    while free > LIMIT:
        folder = queue.pop()
        await download_folder(folder, session)
        _, _, free = await aioshutil.disk_usage("/media/hdd")

...
await asyncio.gather(worker(queue, session) for _ in range(100))


For this case, the queue could just be a list. For more complex cases, you may want to look at asyncio.Queue. It could also be possible to do something with asyncio.Semaphore, though I don't think it's the best tool for this specific use case.
